# Replace comments with comments and block comments according to the number of lines commented, with regular expression in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I would like to transform the following text:

```
some text
% comment line 1
% comment line 2
% comment line 3
some more text
```

into

```
some text
"""
comment line 1
comment line 2
comment line 3
"""
some more text
```

AND in the same file, when there is only one line commented, I would like it to go from

```
some text
% a single commented line
some more text
```

to

```
some text 
# a single commented line
some more text
```

So, when the two cases are in the same file, I would like to go from:

```
some text
% comment line 1
% comment line 2
% comment line 3
some more text
some text
% a single commented line
some more text
```

to

```
some text
"""
comment line 1
comment line 2
comment line 3
"""
some more text
some text 
# a single commented line
some more text
```

What I tried so far, for the second case works as:

```py
re.sub(r'(\A|\r|\n|\r\n|^)% ', r'\1# ',  'some text \n% a single comment line\nsome more text')
```

but it replaces `%` into `#` also when there is more than one line commented.

As for the second case I have failed with:

```py
re.sub(r'(\A|\r|\n|\r\n|^)(% )(.*)(?:\n^\t.*)*', r'"""\3"""',  'some text \n% comment line1\n% comment line 2\n% comment line 3\nsome more text')
```

which repeats the `"""` at each line and conflicts with the case when only one line is commented.

Is there any way to count the consecutive lines where a regular expression is found and change pattern accordingly?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What about `some text # with a comment`? Also, does it have to be a single regex, or can it involve other tools, too?

Comment: @tobias_k He never specified that his code is python code, therefore I think it is wrong to assume that lines with attached comments exist. Sounds more like a markdown language to me.

Comment: @Finomnis I am not assuming anything, that's exactly why I'm asking.

Comment: Yes, in my problem I'm going from a sort of markdown, to another markdown of different sort. The example is willingly not too specific. I can reformulate with C++ syntax, if you prefer, or latex syntax, or anything that has block comments and line comments.

Comment: Ok, syntax changed. Sorry if you will may need to reformulate your answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is probably possible with a regular expression, I think this is much easier without one. You could e.g. use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to detect groups of consecutive commented lines, simply using `str.startswith` to check whether a line is a comment.

```
text = """some text
% comment line 1
% comment line 2
% comment line 3
some more text
some text
% a single commented line
some more text"""

import itertools
for k, grp in itertools.groupby(text.splitlines(), key=lambda s: s.startswith("%")):
    if not k:
        for s in grp:
            print(s)
    else:
        grp = list(grp)
        if len(grp) == 1:
            print("# " + grp[0].lstrip("% "))
        else:
            print('"""')
            for s in grp:
                print(s.lstrip("% "))
            print('"""')
```

This just prints the resulting text, but you can of course also collect it in some string variable and return it. If comments can also start in the middle of a line, you can check this in the `if not k` block. *Here* it would make sense to use `re.sub` to e.g. differentiate between `%` and `\%`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (sorry I slightly changed the syntax of the problem for readability after some comments). Do you think the same can be attained with regexp, or I am making my life more difficult?

Comment: @SeF As I wrote in my first sentence, the answer to both is "probably yes". Is there a particular reason you _want_ this to be a regex?

Comment: I agree with @tobias_k, using regular expressions here would be super difficult. Mainly because you have to match multiple groups at once at the multi-line comment, which is something that python's regex can't do.

Answer (score 1):

Straightforwardly:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    comments = []

    def reformat_comments(comments):
        if len(comments) == 1:
            comments_str = '#' + comments[0] + '\n'
        else:
            comments_str = '"""\n{}\n"""\n'.format('\n'.join(comments))
        return comments_str

    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('% '):
            comments.append(line.lstrip('%'))
        elif comments:
            print(reformat_comments(comments) + line)
            comments = []
        else:
            print(line)
    if comments: print(reformat_comments(comments))
```

Sample output:

```
some text
"""
 comment line 1
 comment line 2
 comment line 3
"""
some more text
some text
# a single commented line
some more text
```

Comment: Okay, this uses regular expressions to check each individual line, but what's the advantage over just using `startswith`?

Comment: Also, I think this will fail if the very last line is a comment line.

Comment: @tobias_k, indeed, that was a mistake (was surprised to myself!). Thanks for catching and ... see my update